# JQuery Dynamic selector to change background color not working

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, selector, angular-grid

I have a `div` for an [AngularGrid](http://www.angulargrid.com/angular-grid-cell-styling/index.php) row which I want to have its background-color changed, it should change on a click event of a callback function for its [cellRendered](http://www.angulargrid.com/angular-grid-cell-rendering/index.php) property:

```
function hightlightedRow(params) {  

            if (params.value) {
               $("div[row='" + params.rowIndex + "']").css('background- color','gray');                    
            } 
 }
```

The code doesn't work for the dynamic rowIndex, but if I hardcode an index like this on this callback event it works fine:

```
if (params.value) {
    $("div[row='3']").css('background-color','gray');
}
```

Can you please tell me how can I change the css style of each row called by this function dynamically?. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Pranav, I have printed, and it has the desired value.

Comment: @Vineet How so?. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it due to the typo ? There's a space after your dash in the CSS property `background- color`.